# Dovecot service starting failed centos, CyberPanel

Tags: php, centos, dovecot, cyber-panel

[Main Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZze2.png)

```
`● dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-02-09 12:10:36 UTC; 3min 7s ago
     Docs: man:dovecot(1)
           https://doc.dovecot.org/
  Process: 1110 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dovecot -F (code=exited, status=89)
  Process: 1106 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/dovecot/prestartscript (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1110 (code=exited, status=89)

Jan 24 02:01:01 vps.marketingmore.in dovecot[537335]: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=642212 uid=0 code=kill)
Jan 24 02:01:02 vps.marketingmore.in systemd[1]: Stopped Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Jan 24 02:01:02 vps.marketingmore.in systemd[1]: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
Jan 24 02:01:03 vps.marketingmore.in prestartscript[642249]: Failed to get unit file state for NetworkManager.service: No such file or directory
Jan 24 02:01:03 vps.marketingmore.in systemd[1]: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Jan 24 02:01:03 vps.marketingmore.in dovecot[642252]: master: Dovecot v2.3.19.1 (9b53102964) starting up for imap, pop3 (core dumps disabled)
Jan 24 03:32:27 vps.marketingmore.in dovecot[642254]: pop3-login: Disconnected: Connection closed: SSL_accept() failed: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol (no auth attempts in 3 secs): user=<>, rip=172.105.147.229, lip=191.101.3.153, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol, session=<xog4Kvrys92saZPl>
Jan 24 12:18:13 vps.marketingmore.in systemd[1]: Stopping Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
Jan 24 12:18:13 vps.marketingmore.in dovecot[642252]: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=533048 uid=0 code=kill)
Jan 24 12:18:14 vps.marketingmore.in systemd[1]: Stopped Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server`.
```

[Email Server Login Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6yMr.png)

Tried to login to cyberpanel email but it shows this error
one of my friend told me to check the server with this command `systemctl status dovecot -l`

and it shows that dovecot.service failed

give me some solutions why this is happening

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found The Solution
its the mail server ssl issue.

1. Run `rm -rf /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com` to remove all mail certificates
2. Run `nano /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf` to remove mail certificate directive

   `local_name mail.mydomain.com { ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/privkey.pem }`

Then run `systemctl restart dovecot && systemctl status dovecot`